# Remoting call to another vf page not working

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I have a vf page where I have a remote mthod from the controller being called. Below is my javascript to call the method `

```
LeadLocatorPreProcessorControllerV2.openLocatorPage($scope.CustomerSite.AddressID,function(results,event){
console.log(results);
                     window.open(results,"_self");
                    });//Abhinav  `
```

and my controller method is

```
`@RemoteAction
    public static PageReference openLocatorPage(String addressId){
        Address__c addr = [SELECT Id, Name, Latitude__c, Longitude__c FROM Address__c WHERE Id = :addressId];
        Decimal latitude = addr.Latitude__c;
        Decimal longitude = addr.Longitude__c;
        String urlLocatorPage = '/apex/LeadLocator?lat='+latitude+'&lon='+longitude;
        PageReference pr = new PageReference(urlLocatorPage);
        return pr;
    }`
```

Now the problem is that my URL formed in the controller is /apex/LeadLocator/lat=1234&lon=1234 but when I log it in console then I get the following url /apex/LeadLocator/lat=1234& amp;lon=1234. 
can someone help me in this why my URL changes and appends amp; to itself in the javascript results. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because javascript will escape the '&' returned from your controller into its entity type`(&amp;)` for security reasons like HTML and script injection, cookie stealing and other web exploits. But because of this behavior your returned url will fail to load, which may cause the link to fail.

What you need to do:

```
var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
textArea.innerHTML    = results;
$scope.urlToLoad      = textArea.value;
$window.location.href = $scope.urlToLoad;  //window.open(results,"_self");
```

This will automatically convert your escaped entities back to normal values and you can open the url. And moreover this doesn't have any security issues.